# Creating e using rational functions

Tags: calculus, rational-functions

This is a follow up question to my original question: [rational function with area e under it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054960/rational-function-with-area-e-under-it). I have stated it more generally and more clearly after discussing it. If there are any improvements to be made to how the question has been stated please make the changes.

Let A be the set of all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $P(x) > 0$ and $\left\vert x\right\vert < r$ where $P$ is a rational function with rational coefficients, $n$ is finite and $r \in \mathbb{Q}$. Does there exist a $P$ and $r$ such that the volume of $A$ (hyper volume, n-dimensional volume, etc.) equals Euler’s constant $e$?

Prove that such a $P$ and $r$ do not exist or find such a $P$ and $r$.

Comment: Other than the fact that it took some iterations via comments and edits to get the original question right, resulting in a slightly rambling wording of the original question, I don't see what was wrong with the older question. Perhaps the words of this question (starting with "Let $A$ be the set") could have been inserted at the beginning of the older question, and some redundant parts later in the question could have been removed to make it easier to read and understand. Evidently opening this as a new question did not elicit better answers than the one already given.